# Adding columns of list within list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have column names in list within list with different size like [["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"]] also few of the columns contains NaN.

### |a b c  d    e   f|

### |1 2 3  4    5   6|

### |1 2 3  Nan NaN  6|

### |1 2 3 4   inf   6|

The result should be the sum of a list within a list like g=a+b+c, h=d+e, i=f which are column names. NaN sum should result NaN, not 0.
How to do that in a loop?

Expected Output

### |g h   i|

### |6 9   6|

### |6 NaN 6|

|6 inf 6|

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Expected Output added

Comment: Super, answer was edited, please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
L = [["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"]]

a = [df[x].sum(axis=1, min_count=1) for x in L]
```

Loop solution:

```
a = []
for x in L:
    a.append(df[x].sum(axis=1, min_count=1))
```

---

```
print (a)
[0    6
1    6
2    6
dtype: int64, 0    9.0
1    NaN
2    inf
dtype: float64, 0    6
1    6
2    6
dtype: int64]
```

And then add [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat(a, axis=1, keys=['g','h','i'])
print (df1)
   g    h  i
0  6  9.0  6
1  6  NaN  6
2  6  inf  6
```